# pip3 installs to wrong directory

Tags: raspbian, python, pip

For some reason, pip3 does not install packages to the proper dist-packages directory, at least not the directory I expect.

I am trying to install the package cleverwrap currently, but this happens for all packages installed with pip3 as far as I can tell.

I am running this command:

```
sudo pip3 install cleverwrap
```

This command installs to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`

Shouldn't it install to `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/` ?

```
crawforc3@raspberrypi:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.9

crawforc3@raspberrypi:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.2

crawforc3@raspberrypi:~$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

crawforc3@raspberrypi:~$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3

crawforc3@raspberrypi:~$ python3 -m pip install cleverwrap
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip

crawforc3@raspberrypi:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Output from 
    pip3 show cleverwrap

```
crawforc3@raspberrypi:~$ pip3 show cleverwrap
Name: cleverwrap
Version: 0.2.3.2
Summary: A wrapper for the official cleverbot.com API
Home-page: https://github.com/edwardslabs/cleverwrap.py
Author: Andrew Edwards
Author-email: andrewthomasedwards@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: requests
```

@Hydraxan14 suggested this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407208/pip3-4-v-refers-to-python2-7-installation/35182033#35182033

I changed where pip looks for python3. This resulted in a version conflict. *Something* was looking for a different version of pip than was installed.

Output from pip3 -V

```
crawforc3@raspberrypi:/usr/local/bin$ pip3 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 449, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 745, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 644, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 1.5.6 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==9.0.1'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2876, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 451, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 464, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 639, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==9.0.1
```

Updating pip3 with this command solved the version conflict and everything works now.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade
```

Comment: What directory do you expect it to install to?What directory does it install to? Given that you have repeatedly installed/uninstalled you may be best off startingf with a fresh install. What package(s) are you trying to install?

Comment: @SteveRobillard pip, pip2, and pip3 all install  to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages instead of /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages.

Comment: First, you have only answered one of the many questions I asked. Second, the answers belong in your question not the comments. What pip command are you using to install?

Comment: @SteveRobillard You asked three questions, I answered two directly and the other is in the question itself. You're not being helpful so why even reply?

Comment: What command exactly are you running?

Comment: the command you should be running is sudo pip3 install cleverwrap and you can verify where it was installed, and the version installed with pip3 show cleverwrap

Comment: I have been using sudo, it's not a permission issue I don't think. I'll edit the question with the output from pip3 show cleverwrap

Comment: @Chris What's the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) for pip3?  [It may not be running with python3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35182033/7351717).  Run `head -n 1 $(which pip3)` to see the shebang.

Comment: @Hydraxan14 #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: I think the root cause is your admitted tinkering. I just ran the install on one of my Pi's and got Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages from pip show cleverwrap. As I mentioned it may be best to reimage your SD card and start fresh.

Comment: Further evidence is that the output of  which pip3 for you returns /usr/local/bin/pip3 not /usr/bin/pip3

Comment: How did you install pip and pip3? On a properly-maintained Raspbian system (`sudo apt install python-pip python3-pip`) they should be in /usr/bin, not /usr/local/bin. Did you install your own version(s) of Python? Something has caused a mismatch in your library search path, and Python is confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## @Hydraxan14's answer got me going in the right direction.

> pip3 is being run with python2.7
>
> I found [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35182033/7351717) which might pertain to this situation.
>
> ---

### Summary

> Basically, `/usr/local/pip3` has the `#!/usr/bin/python` [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) as its first line, which causes it to be run by the python2.7 interpreter, and not the python3 interpreter.
>
> This might be causing your issue.
>
> The linked answer mentions changing `pip3`'s shebang to `#!/usr/bin/python3` to force it to be run with the python3 interpreter.

---

After making the change suggested in the link that @Hydraxan14 suggested, I was left with a pip3 version conflict which was easily fixed by updating pip3 by running:

```
python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

## pip3 is being run with python2.7

I found [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35182033/7351717) which might pertain to this situation.

---

### Summary

Basically, `/usr/local/pip3` has the `#!/usr/bin/python` [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) as its first line, which causes it to be run by the python2.7 interpreter, and not the python3 interpreter.

This might be causing your issue.

The linked answer mentions changing `pip3`'s shebang to `#!/usr/bin/python3` to force it to be run with the python3 interpreter.

---

I hope this helps!

Comment: Running cat /usr/bin/pip3 shows #!/usr/bin/python3 so this is not likely the cause.

Comment: @Hydraxan14 This answer causes a version conflict. However, running python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade fixed that.  If you want to add this to the answer I qill accept it.

Comment: @Chris That sounds like something quite different than what I suggested.  Perhaps it would be best if you posted that as a separate answer.